# notification not creating on user mention

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm not getting a notification on user mention. Anytime I mention a user on a post, I want to send the mentioned user notification, but anytime I create a post and mention a user, the notification is not be created I don't know what I'm doing wrong

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=@)(\w+)/mi', $this->body, $matchedMentions, 
    PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

foreach ($matchedMentions as $matchedMention) {
    if ($user = User::where('username', $matchedMention[0])->first()) {
        optional($this->user)->notify(new MentionsNotify($user));
    }
}
```

here is my Notification trait

```
class MentionsNotify extends Notification
{
  use Queueable;

/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['mail', 'database'];
}

/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
        ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
        ->line('Thank you for using our application!', [
            'user' => $this->user,
        ]);
}

/**
 * Get the array representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'user_id' => $this->user->id,
        'post_body' => $this->post->body,
        // 'user_avatar' => $this->post->user->getAvatar(),
        'user_name' => $this->post->user->name,
        'post_id' => $this->post->post->id,
    ];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your foreach should be like this :

```
foreach ($matchedMentions as $matchedMention) {
   optional(User::where('username', $matchedMention[0])->first(), function ($user) {
       $user->notify(new MentionsNotify($user));
   });
}
```

For more : https://laravel-news.com/laravel-optional-helper